# How do I select users that have not had their score updated within the last 2 hours or at all using Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have the following 2 tables...

**users**

```
user_id, name, age
```

**user_score**

```
score_id, user_id, score, date(timestamp)
```

The user_score table should keep a log of all scores for all users updated every 2 hours.

So I need to get a list of all user ids that have not had their score updated in the last 2 hours or at all (for new players). I'm guessing I will have to use INNER JOIN?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you are guessing (and your guess is almost right), did you also try something?

Comment: Yup use inner join and a where clause to check the timestamp, you might be able to do this in one sql query using SUBTIME()

Comment: `select user_id from user_score where now()-date > (1000*60*2)` why to join when you want select only user_id

Comment: The answer depends on how your data gets written.  When a score is updated, do you add new rows or update existing ones?

Comment: @Jan'splite'Kondelík This will select all users, that have any record older than 2 hours. Even those that have updated in last 2 hours.

Comment: @HonzaHaering ah, you are right... (removed my comment, there is real answer ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `left join` or `not exists`.  You simply need all records with no activity in the past two hours (this would include new users too):

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1 from user_score us
                  where u.user_id = us.user_id and
                        us.date >= date_sub(now(), interval 2 hour)
                 );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your answer. I never thought of it like that! I had to remove that first opening bracket though to make it work 'select u.*( '.